# How to configure SignalR with Global.asax instead of Startup.cs in ASP MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

SignalR Requires Owin Startup Class, but my application works with Global.asax class.

```
public class Startup
{
   public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
   {
      app.MapSignalR();
   }
}
```

if I add the startup class, my asp MVC project will have two start classes (global and startup), is it OK? or I should only apply one of them and move my global class to startup class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can mark which class in an assembly will be automatically used by `Owin` in the startup.

In my example, I declared it in the `Startup` and pointed to it using `OwinStartup`
e.g.

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using System.Net;
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(YourProject.Startup))]


namespace YourProject
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
            {
                EnableDetailedErrors = true
            };
            app.MapSignalR(hubConfiguration);
        }
    }
}
```

If you are using `Owin`, you must use the `Startup` class instead of the `Global.asax`.

Comment: thank you, but what's gonna happen for the global.asax class, should I move my code to start up, or I can keep both of them ??please clarify

Comment: The main objective is to trigger the signalR settings when the application start. I suggest you can moved it to the `Startup` class.